# Unit test Angular directive that accesses external element

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that uses an attribute to specify another control that it modifies.

Directive definition object:

```
{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
    scope: {
        targetId: '@'
    },
    controller: MyController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
}
```

A function on the directive's controller modifies the contents of the target element (an input field):

```
function onSelection (value) {
    var $element = $('#' + vm.targetId);

    $element.val('calculated stuff');
    $element.trigger('input');
}
```

The unit tests (Jasmine/Karma/PhantomJS) currently append the element to the page. This works, but it seems like a code smell.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var elementHtml = '<my-directive target-id="bar"></my-directive>' +
        '<input type="text" id="bar">';

    scope = $rootScope.$new();    
    angularElement = angular.element(elementHtml);
    angularElement.appendTo(document.body);  // HELP ME KILL THIS!
    element = $compile(angularElement)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
}));

afterEach(function () {
    angularElement.remove();  // HELP ME KILL THIS!
});
```

I've tried rewriting the controller function to avoid jQuery; this did not help.

How can I revise the directive or the tests to eliminate the appendTo/remove?

Comment: It is much bigger code smell that you use ids in your directive. It is very jQuery style and not "Angular way". Consider using `require` in directives on same branch of DOM tree, or "common-parent" or "global service" approaches otherwises (you can search or ask another question if you don't know how to do that - explanation is definitely out of scope of this question)

Comment: @ValentynShybanov I am open to solutions that involve revising the directive. The actual purpose of this directive is to insert mail-merge placeholders in an input or textarea field (which should not be part of the directive template, and I'd rather avoid transclusion). If you'd like to post an example of your recommended method or links to this I would consider accepting that as an answer.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to kill the add / remove element from your code without refactoring the `onSelection()` function. Is there any reason you can't bind an `ng-model` to your #bar input? If you could do that, then you could just set the value in the controller without needing to grab the element with jQuery.

Comment: @jperezov The issue is that the directive needs the current selection and/or cursor position in the target element, not just the bound text. It inserts a selected value in that place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to migrate the directive to an attribute instead of an element. This removes the need for the `target-id` attribute and you don't need to hunt for the target element.

See http://jsfiddle.net/morloch/621rp33L/

**Directive**

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    var targetElement;
    function MyController() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.onSelection = function() {
        targetElement.val('calculated stuff');
        targetElement.trigger('input');
      }
    }
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        targetId: '@'
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        targetElement = element;
      },
      controller: MyController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };
  });
```

**Test**

```
describe('Directive: myDirective', function() {
  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('testApp'));

  var element, controller, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<input my-directive type="text" id="bar">');
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    controller = element.controller('myDirective');
  }));

  it('should have an empty val', inject(function() {
    expect(element.val()).toBe('');
  }));

  it('should have a calculated val after select', inject(function() {
    controller.onSelection();
    expect(element.val()).toBe('calculated stuff');
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you - this is definitely one approach. One drawback is that it's more difficult to say "I want the directive control here on the page" and "I want it to affect the control at this location on the page."

Comment: Another option then (since you need direct access to the input tag) is to use two directives, one as the control (where the user makes the selection) and another (on the input) that applies the results, using a signal to communicate that an action has taken place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another suggestion that keeps your logic almost exactly the same: use a second directive to make the target `element` available on the controller, which you can then pass to your primary directive for processing: http://jsfiddle.net/morloch/p8r2Lz1L/

**getElement**

```
  .directive('getElement', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        getElement: '='
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.getElement = element;
      }
    };
  })
```

**myDirective**

```
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    function MyController() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.onSelection = function() {
        vm.targetElement.val('calculated stuff');
        vm.targetElement.trigger('input');
      }
    }
    return {
      template: '<div></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        targetElement: '='
      },
      controller: MyController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };
  })
```

**Test**

```
describe('Directive: myDirective', function() {
  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('testApp'));

  var element, controller, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<input get-element="elementBar" type="text" id="bar"><my-directive target-element="elementBar"></my-directive>');
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    controller = $(element[1]).controller('myDirective');
  }));

  it('should have an empty val', inject(function() {
    expect($(element[0]).val()).toBe('');
  }));

  it('should have a calculated val after select', inject(function() {
    controller.onSelection();
    expect($(element[0]).val()).toBe('calculated stuff');
  }));
});
```